# Hadoop: get Machine hostname for a particular MapReuce task

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any way to get the `Machine hostname` for a particular `attempt` of a `task` programmatically ?

The same information is displayed in the `jobracker WebUI` of hadoop, like below:

[image]

Below is what I have known so far to achieve this:

```
    // How to instantiate JobTracker ??
    JobTracker tracker = (JobTracker) application.getAttribute("job.tracker");

    JobID jobidObj = JobID.forName(jobid);
    JobInProgress job = tracker.getJob(jobidObj);
    TaskID tipidObj = TaskID.forName(tipid);
    TaskInProgress tip = job.getTaskInProgress(tipidObj);
    TaskStatus[] ts = tip.getTaskStatuses();
    for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
        TaskStatus status = ts[i];

        //get the attempt name
        String taskTrackerName = status.getTaskTracker();

        TaskTrackerStatus taskTracker = tracker.getTaskTracker(taskTrackerName);

        //get the hostname
        taskTracker.getHost();
    }
```

This is the only way I know to get the hostname but these codes will never work because I could not get any way to instantiate `JobTracker`. Please let me know if there is any other way, if the above codes have no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MAPREDUCE-2818](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2818) it doesn't look like a public API for that information made it into MRv1. The workaround from the JIRA is to request the JobTracker UI page programmatically and parse the hostname from that.

If you instead use MRv2 you can programmatically get the hostname of a task attempt from the [YARN REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html).